# Generate List of custom Actions Taken by a specific user in my app

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql, facebook-opengraph, open-graph-beta

Hi I've developed a Facebook app that allows user to take custom actions that result in custom open graph objects. I would now like to generate lists of what actions specific users have taken in my app. is this information stored somewhere in the open graph? Do I need to use FQL? Can anyone point me in a good direction?

Much Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The developer tool has a "Get Code" link. Click it and you can see how to read all the actions.

Comment: Hey you're the admin for the Open Graph Protocol Facebook group! Works like a charm...thanks a billion!